# StaticUserAuthenticator does not set FTP username in VFS2

Tags: java, ftp, vfs, apache-commons-vfs

I am trying to user the StaticUserAuthenticator with an FTP connection through ApacheVFS2 - I have the following code:

```
this.fsOptions = new FileSystemOptions();
StaticUserAuthenticator auth = new StaticUserAuthenticator(null, username, password); 
DefaultFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserAuthenticator(fsOptions, auth); 
this.fsManager = VFS.getManager();

// ... later

FileObject file = fsManager.resolveFile("ftp://myhost:21/pathtofile.ext".toString(), fsOptions);
FileContent content = file.getContent();
```

This results in the following exception being thrown:

org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not read file "ftp://myhost:21/pathtofile.ext".
Caused by: sun.net.ftp.FtpLoginException: user anonymous : 501 Use user@site to connect via proxy

When I run a network trace on this I see that the user arg passed to the FTP server is 'anonymous'
T 10.161.37.176:57650 -> 10.152.4.138:21 [AP]
  USER anonymous..

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Cannot comment yet, clumsyjedi I tried only with the passive mode change, which works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, not as tricky as I thought

```
UserAuthenticator auth = new StaticUserAuthenticator("", username, password); 
DefaultFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserAuthenticator(fsOptions, auth); 
FtpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setPassiveMode(fsOptions, true);
```

Not sure if it's the non-null first arg to the StaticUserAuthenticator constructor, or the passive mode that did it, but with those changes it works.